# How to put some delay after certain time interval in load runner?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, loadrunner

I am using load runner tool for  performance testing. I want to put some delay after certain interval of time like every 5 minutes.
Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code,

```
sleep(1000*60*5);
```

Example:

```
    web_add_cookie(<bla bla bla bla>);

    sleep(1000*60*5);

    web_link(<bla bla bla bla>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pacing in run time settings

sleep(300000);

If you are adding a delay to allow a slow server to respond then you are on the wrong path

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your response. Actually I don't want to put delay after each iteration. My goal is to put some delay after certain intervals i.e. 10 Vusers are running (Start with 1 Vuser) and ramp up with 1 Vuser every 10 minutes. So, my goal is to put some delay after 20 minutes. I want to achieve this.